# Unity - Object hiting soon the other object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a replica project to the game Knife Hit. And I'm having trouble with the following question, is my knife hitting the target before it hits it, or the target is detecting the hit before the knife even arrives. What causes the knife to fly around the target, where it should be stuck on the target. As shown in the image below. Consequently, the spawn of the knives that stay on the target, which is to hinder the gameplay, happen the same, are born and are flying around the target.

[image]

The code i use is this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (shoot)
    {
        lastPosition = transform.position;
        transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(lastPosition, transform.position);
         if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            shoot = false;
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Knife")
            {
                Level.Instance.HitWrong();
                rigidbody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
                rigidbody.AddTorque(10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.y);
                transform.parent = hit.transform;
                collider.enabled = true;
                Level.Instance.HitSucced(rigidbody);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question.. also please use the tags correctly .. this had nothing to do with `visual-studio` nor `visual-studio-code` and note that your code is in `c#` and not in `unityscript` which is - or better said **was** - a custom JavaScript flavor like programming language which was used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now

Comment: My knifes are not hitting on the target(the wood circle). They supposedly are detecting the hit, before to reach the target.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your 2D colliders are properly "cutout" outlined... My guess is that your 2D collider is really big around the knife or target